# Laravel Paginate method takes too much time for 1 million record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization, pagination

So this is my case. I have a main table `payment_transactions` having almost 1 million records.
I am getting the data from this table with joins and where clauses and there is Laravel `paginate` method,
But this method takes too much time and after investigation, I found that its count method is taking time like 4 to 5 seconds just for counting.

So how can I optimize and speed up this query, especially is there any way to improve paginate method speed?

`Note:` I can't use `simplePaginate` because there is a datatable on frontend and I need a total count for that.

So for paginate, two queries run
1 is the main query and other one is for count, and I felt that, the count query is taking much time.

Here is the count query after `getQueryLog`

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `payment_transactions` 
left join `users` as `U` on `U`.`id` = `payment_transactions`.`user_id`
left join `coupons` as `C`
on `C`.`id` = `payment_transactions`.`coupon_id` 
where `payment_transactions`.`refund_status` = 'NO_REFUND'
and `payment_transactions`.`transaction_type` 
in ('BOOKING','SB_ANPR','QUERCUS_ANPR','CANDID_ANPR','SB_TICKET',
'ORBILITY_TICKET','TOPUP,CREDIT','DEBIT','GIFT')
and `payment_transactions`.`status` != 'INITIATED'
```

Here is my code example:

```
//Get Transactions data
public function adminTransactions(Request $request) 
{
    $selectableFields = [
            'payment_transactions.id', 'payment_transactions.transaction_id AS transaction_id',
    'payment_transactions.refund_status',
            'payment_transactions.created_at', 'payment_transactions.response_data', 'payment_transactions.status',
            'payment_transactions.transaction_type', 'payment_transactions.payment_mode','payment_transactions.payment_source',
            'payment_transactions.subtotal', 'payment_transactions.service_fees', 'C.coupon_code','C.amount AS coupon_value',
            DB::raw("IF(payment_transactions.refund_remarks='NULL','-NA-',payment_transactions.refund_remarks) as refund_remarks"),
            DB::raw("IF(payment_transactions.transaction_type='TOPUP' AND payment_transactions.coupon_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND payment_transactions.coupon_id!=0,
payment_transactions.amount + C.amount,payment_transactions.amount) as amount"),
            DB::raw("CONCAT(U.first_name,' ',U.last_name)  AS username"), 'U.id AS user_id',
            DB::raw("JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(payment_transactions.response_data, '$.description')) AS description"),
            DB::raw("payment_transactions.invoice_id"),
            DB::raw("JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(payment_transactions.response_data, '$.Data.PaymentID')) AS upay_payment_id"),
        ];
       
    return PaymentTransactions::select($selectableFields)
            ->with('homeScreenMessages:payment_transaction_id,from_name,message,amount')
            ->leftJoin('users AS U', 'U.id', '=', 'payment_transactions.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('coupons AS C', 'C.id', '=', 'payment_transactions.coupon_id')
        ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(U.first_name,' ',U.last_name)"), 'like', "%{$request->input('query')}%")
            ->orWhere('U.id', $request->input('query'))
            ->orWhere("U.phone_number", "LIKE", "%" . $request->input('query') . "%")
            ->orWhere("U.email", "LIKE", "%" . $request->input('query') . "%")
        ->orWhere('payment_transactions.id', $request->input('query'))
            ->orWhere('payment_transactions.transaction_id', $request->input('query'));
}

//Paginate function
 public function paginationCalculate($queryObject, $request) {
        $draw = $request->get('draw');
        $start = $request->get("start");
        $rowperpage = $request->get("length"); // Rows display per page

        $columnIndex_arr = $request->get('order');
        $columnName_arr = $request->get('columns');
        $order_arr = $request->get('order');

        $columnIndex = $columnIndex_arr[0]['column']; // Column index
        $columnName = $columnName_arr[$columnIndex]['name']; // Column name
        $columnSortOrder = $order_arr[0]['dir']; // asc or desc
        $pageNumber = ($start + $rowperpage) / $rowperpage;
        if(!empty($columnName)) {
            $queryObject->orderBy($columnName, $columnSortOrder);
        }
        $records = $queryObject->paginate($rowperpage, ['*'], 'page', $pageNumber)->toArray();

        return array(
            "draw" => intval($draw),
            "recordsFiltered" => $records['total'],
            "recordsTotal" => $records['total'],
            "data" => $records['data']
        );
    }
```

Comment: I assume you have indexed the correct columns? You could test how long the query takes if you remove all lines containing `$request->input('query')`. If that is fast enough then you know that's causing the slowness. There are other ways to search in a database, but before you look into that, you first you need to confirm that this is really the cause.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I added all possible `index` on database, as well as tested without `$request->input`  and after `getQueryLog `  I found that there is a count in pagination that is taking time, so I removed this just for testing and note that almost 4 to 5 second time reduced.

Comment: Sorry, I read your answer, but it still don't know what effect the removal of all lines containing `$request->input('query')` has. Note that I write "removal of all lines", and not just having an empty `$request->input('query')`. If you have used `getQueryLog`, and  you think you know what the problem is, tell us, preferably by editing your question, not in a comment. What kind of "count in pagination" are you talking about?

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. OK, I get it. I notice that the count query joins the `users` and `coupons` tables, but they are not actually used to create the count. If you remove them, and then make sure that the `transaction_type` and `status` columns have an index, then that query should be pretty fast. Note that you can combine multiple columns into one index.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, Thanks for your reply, I'll try as per your suggestions.
However I tried after adding the index, But I think did not try with the composite index as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want "LEFT".  With LEFT, the COUNT will count payment transactions even if there is no matching user and/or coupon.

Or maybe there are *multiple* users or coupons for each payment_transaction?  In this case, the COUNT will be inflated.  To fix this, simply remove the two extra tables.

Regardless of the situation, add this composite (and covering) index to `payment_transactions`:

```
INDEX(refund_status, transaction_type, status, user_id, coupon_id)
```

`refund_type` must be first since it is tested with '='.

If that is not "fast enough", then I must ask you "Who cares what the exact number when there are a million rows?"  Do you ever see a search engine giving an exact number of hits?  Does that imprecision bother you?

That is, rethink the requirement to calculate the exact number of rows.  Or even an approximate number.

You mentioned "pagination".  Please show us how that is done.  `OFFSET` is an inefficient way since it rescans the previously seen rows again and again.  Instead, 'remember where you left off':  [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Answer (score 0):

You HAVE to adding INDEX to your MySQL database.  Makes it lighting fast!

If you are using Navicat, click on the Index tab, and add the Column name and Name it the same.  You WILL notice a huge difference.